# txt file parsing in python, repetition of a line

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
for line in contents:
        line_fields = line.strip().split()
        f2.write("ID: " + line_fields[0] + '\n')
        f2.write("Name:" + line_fields[1] + '\n')
```

What I am trying to do is write ID only once for each number contained in line_fields[0]. So, it should look like the left instead of the right column:

```
ID: 1              ID: 1
Name1              Name1
Name1              ID: 1
ID: 2              Name1
Name2              ID: 2
Name2              Name2
...
```

I am actually quite confused and would be very grateful to get some advice from you

Comment: Feels like you need to save what you have in the file in a dictionary before writing it to the second file

Comment: It is hard to say something w/o seeing of contents var. What is there?

Comment: Isn't there any method to check whether a certain content from line_fields[0] was already written?

Comment: I think you have to keep track of it separately before writing it to the file.

Comment: When you look at `line_fields[0]`, can you think of a rule that tells you whether or not to write it out? Maybe something that involves keeping track of the value you wrote last time?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the values from that field goes from 0 one by one

Comment: Your question is really unclear. From your code `line_fields` is a list. But you are saying for each number contained in `line_fields[0]`, you need to write ID. I dont understand whats the format of multiple numbers within `line_field[0]`. In that case I will have to guess and assume which I dont want to do. For example: Is your line_fields[0] something like "1:2:3:4" or "1234" or "1-2-3-4".

Comment: From the code and output of the code, I have to assume the input file which seems to be something like:
Based on your output on right and code:
1 1\n
1 1\n
2 2\n

Based on your output on left and code:
I cant guess the input file

In short, please provide the input file you are parsing.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for asking the question.
You can use dictionary as check mechanism to view the repeated values.
As pointed out by author

```
d = {}
for line in contents:
        line_fields = line.strip().split()
        if line_fields[0] not in d.keys():
            f2.write("ID: " + line_fields[0] + '\n')
            f2.write("Name:" + line_fields[0] + '\n')
            d[line_fields[0]] = line_fields[1]
```

Comment: now it is just writing it once and misses the next fields that should be under the same ID. So it goes id1, id2, id3 straight

Comment: could you please give example for text file.

Comment: ok, thanks. It works fine: I corrected it a bit: in 'if'  there is only the line with ID and then d[line_fields[0]] = line_fields[0]

Comment: happy it worked for you !!

Answer (score -1):

If you dont want to deal with dicts you can do this:

```
current = ""
for line in contents:
        line_fields = line.strip().split()
        if current != line_fields[0]:
            f2.write("ID: " + line_fields[0] + '\n')
            current = line_fields[0]
        f2.write("Name:" + line_fields[1] + '\n')
```

It will only write ID if it is different from the previous one.